# Github Actions v4 API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions

I need to interact with Github Actions through some code. I found the [v3 API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/) for that, but I've been migrating code to use the v4 API instead. I have not been able to find anything related to github actions on v4, unfortunately. Using introspection won't show "artifacts" or "workflows", except for copying the latter on `CloneProjectInput`, but, perhaps, there's a feature flag I need to use to get them.

Is there any way to interact with Github Actions through their v4 API?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet: the GitHub Actions API [announced last January 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-27-github-actions-api-beta/) is:

- still in beta
- using the [V3 API only](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/)

Note that there is a difference between:

- [GitHub REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/)
- [GitHub GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/)

For now, Actions are exposed through REST, not [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL)

The [request has been made of course](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GraphQL-Actions-API/m-p/54454):

> As of now, the GitHub Actions API enables you to manage GitHub Actions only using the REST API.
>   I'll be sure to pass on your request for v4 support to the team for consideration.

(that was mid-April 2020)

Comment: Funny that the request has been "solved" with a comment that amounted to "I'll mention that", so there's no way of actually track it.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Yes, the GitHub way to interract with its user base is different from GitLab (where every issue/request for enhancenement is public)